# VIES VAT validation wsdl is not working via java code

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

The EU VIES VAT  validation from WSDL is not working when running via java code. But the same is working from some soap API testing tools.
 Eg, https://wsdlbrowser.com/soapclient?wsdl_url=https%3A%2F%2Fec.europa.eu%2Ftaxation_customs%2Fvies%2FcheckVatService.wsdl and https://app.boomerangapi.com/?ext

Even its not working when I trid to get source code from wsimport. (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin>wsimport -keep -verbose http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl)

Error is “The element type "BR" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".” The same error is coming when trying to access SOAP service via java code.

Any suggestions on how to use this EU wsdl for validating VAT nos?

Answer (score 1):

Change protocol http:// to http**s**:// in the WSDL URL

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using 'JAX-WS' Maven plugin to parse a WSDL file to generate java classes.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.12</version>

<execution>
    <id>wsimportb-from-jdk</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>wsimport</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlUrls>
            <wsdlUrl>
            https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl
        </wsdlUrl>
        </wsdlUrls>
        <keep>true</keep>
        <packageName>com.vies</packageName>
        <sourceDestDir>target/generatedclasses</sourceDestDir>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Then export your `com.vies` custom package under maven `<Export-Package>`